# How to use threading on dictionaries to improve time complexity?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

I am new to threading. What I know is we can call threads on functions, but I want to call it on a dictionary.

I have a dictionary which have random numbers present in different indexes. I want to find the sum of all those numbers. What I want to do is basically to use a thread for every single row/index of that dictionary. That single thread will find sum of all the numbers in that specific row and then these sums of all the threads will be summed together to get me the final result.

```
import random
import time

li = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"
, "v", "w", "x", "y"]

arr = {}

for k in range(0, 25):
    arr[li[k]] = [random.randrange(1, 10, 1) for i in range(1000000)]

start = time.perf_counter()

sum = 0
for k, v in arr.items():
    for value in v:
        sum += value 

end = time.perf_counter()

print(sum)

print("Finished in: ", round(end-start, 2), " seconds")
```

I used to do it the simple way and it took me about 86 seconds in total (due to assigning of numbers to dictionary) and 5 seconds total to calculate the sum.

I want to improve those 5 seconds of the sum calculation by creating thread for every single index of the dictionary. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Python threading will probably not help you at all due to the GIL making only one thread at a time run Python code.

Comment: (Multiprocessing could help, *if* you also do the summing for each list in the subprocess, treating this as a map-reduce problem.)

Comment: @AKX can you tell me regarding this second approach of Multiprocessing? How can we use that approach to improve the timing here? I have a very similar problem to the sample problem I gave above but its taking too much time to compute the final value, however I know that I can do it the way I mentioned above (calculate a sum value for each index separately and then summing up all those sum values)

Comment: ..but be aware that multiprocessing entails a lot of overhead, so may not speed things up at all and can even slow them down.

Comment: Does your real problem really involve generating random numbers – in other words, how do you _really_ get the numbers that need to be summed up? That's crucial to figuring out whether multiprocessing can help you due to the overheads involved.

Comment: @martineau yes, multiprocessing takes more time than threading... but it is at least worth a try I suppose

Comment: @AKX No, they are not random numbers. It's basically numbers taken from a Database (these numbers are user entered so they can be considered random). Each Index contains different numbers. My problem requires finding of duplicate numbers in each index and then summing up all those duplicate numbers. For that, I have to use two for loops for each index which finds out the total number of duplicates in each index and then sum up the number of duplicates of all indexes/rows to calculate the final value.

Comment: That sounds like something your database (assuming it's an SQL database) can do very efficiently without any Python code involved.

Comment: Frequently the problem is getting data to and from the subprocesses from the main process because each one runs in its own memory-space so there are no global variables can't be shared like they can when multithreading.

Comment: @martineau In this case, if OP can delegate the data fetching to the subprocess, that wouldn't be a problem. To this point it's not clear whether each key in `arr` is independent of the others, though.

Comment: @AKX not exaclty, its actually much more complex than that. It's actually a fitness function of Genetic Algorithm, however the data is being taken from database... But for each new generation, the numbers in each index/row can be changed so I can't really do this using SQL (I could but only for the first generation and not again).

Comment: @AsadHussain Just saying, it would have been useful if this information was in the original post instead of a trivialized "sum random numbers" thing. ;-) But anyway: instead of `arr[x] = [random.randrange...]` you could have `arr[x] = get_values(x)`? And would all of the items in `arr` be independent of one another?

Comment: @AKX Hmm, I wanted to keep the post simple so made a very basic example. Although, I didn't know that threading can not be done in Python, so I guess I should make a new post which would explain the whole scenario of mine including my algorithm and that should actually help understand it much better...... random.range was used again, just to create a sample problem....... And yes, all the items are independent of each other in the arr.

Comment: Many times oversimplifying an example makes it an entirely different exercise. But anyway, now that we've gotten an idea of the actual thing you're working on, I can cook up an example answer.

Comment: That would be amazing, Thank you! ^_^

Comment: Just an aside, no amount of threading helps with "time complexity" if what you are talking about is "Big O". A quadratic function is still quadratic when divided by a constant such as the number of CPUs.

Comment: @JonSG No no, I think I used a wrong term here (time complexity). What I meant to say is the total time my program would take to calculate the sum. That time (not time complexity) can definitely be increased by using something similar to threading in this case.

Comment: Just recently read that if you have HTT (Hyper-Threading Technology) on your machine then process based timing results will not be reliable. The recommendation is to use a time stamp counter.  (Intel64 and 32 Architectures Software Developers Manual volume3 chapter 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here's an example of how you'd use `multiprocessing` for a "map-reduce" style summing problem.

This very much assumes each subproblem (as represented by `process_key`) is independent of the rest.

The final reduction (summing all key results together) is done by the main program.

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import string
import time
from typing import Tuple, List


def get_key_data(key: str) -> List[int]:
    # Get data for a given key from a database or wherever;
    # here we just get a big blob of random bytes.
    return list(os.urandom(1_000_000))


def process_key(key: str) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    # This function is run in a separate process,
    # so it can't access global data in the same way a function
    # in the same process could.  Program accordingly.
    key_data = get_key_data(key)
    result_for_key = sum(key_data)  # Could be heavier computation here...

    # Returning a tuple makes it easier to work with the keyed data in the main program.
    return (key, result_for_key)


def main():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    keys = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        results = {}
        # Since result order doesn't matter, we can use `imap_unordered` to optimize performance.
        # It would also be worth adding `chunksize=...` to spend less time in serializers.
        for key, result in p.imap_unordered(process_key, keys):  # unpacking result tuples here
            print(f"Got result {result} for key {key}")
            results[key] = result
    grand_total = sum(results.values())
    end = time.perf_counter()

    print(f"Grand total: {grand_total} in {end - start:.2f} seconds")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This prints out (something like)

```
Got result 127439637 for key y
Got result 127521766 for key z
Got result 127410016 for key a
Got result 127618358 for key b
Got result 127510624 for key c
Got result 127525228 for key d
Got result 127471359 for key e
Got result 127535553 for key f
Got result 127457231 for key m
Got result 127547738 for key n
Got result 127567059 for key o
Got result 127470823 for key g
Got result 127465435 for key h
Got result 127497010 for key i
Got result 127432593 for key j
Got result 127555330 for key k
Got result 127402226 for key l
Got result 127534939 for key p
Got result 127558057 for key q
Got result 127474231 for key r
Got result 127491137 for key v
Got result 127520358 for key w
Got result 127490582 for key x
Got result 127489005 for key s
Got result 127485159 for key t
Got result 127503702 for key u
Grand total: 3314975156 in 0.60 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

> I know...we can call threads on functions.

Nope. You can't *call* a thread on anything. When you write this:

```py
thread = threading.Thread(foobar, args=(x, y, z))
```

You're not calling a thread. You are calling the *constructor* of the `Thread` class. The constructor makes a new `Thread` object, and then it's the `Thread` that does the calling: The `Thread` calls `foobar(x, y, z)`.

> What I want to do is basically to use a thread for every single row/index of that dictionary. That single thread will find sum of all the numbers in that specific row and...

Threads run code, and you have to provide the code that a thread will run in the form of a function. If you wanted a thread to "find the sum of all the numbers in a specific row..,"* then you'd have to write a function that finds the sum of all of the numbers, and then you'd have to create a new `Thread` that would call your function.

---

* *Some of the other answers and comments on your question explain how Python's Global Interpreter Lock (a.k.a., the GIL) prevents you from using threads to make your program run any faster. So, the rest of this answer is fantasy because it won't make your program faster, but it* does *illustrate how to create threads.*

---

Probably, you'll want to pass the dictionary and the row number to the function as arguments. Maybe you'll also want to pass it some mutable result structure (e.g., an array) into which the function can save the result.

```py
def FindRowSum(dictionary, row, results):
    sum = 0
    for ...:
        sum = sum + ...
    results[row] = sum

...

allThreads = []
results = []
for row in range(...):
    thread = threading.Thread(FindRowSum, args=(myDictionary, row, results))
    allThreads.append(thread)
```

Then, further on down, if you want to wait for all of the threads to finish their work:

```py
for thread in allThreads:
    thread.join()
```